# Combining elements on an rdd of tuple5 based on one of the entires in tuple in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD in which each element is a tuple of length 5. Say for example:

```
(Cricket,Game,Outdoor,India, yes)
(Cricket,Game,Outdoor,Australia, yes)
(Hockey,Game,Outdoor,India,yes)
```

I want to add all entries with same game name in one as:

```
(Cricket,[Game,Outdoor,India,yes],[Game,Outdoor,Australia,yes])
```

How can I do it in scala?

Comment: It should be irrespective of game name pr game specific ?

Comment: sorry. I want them to add with the same game name. Question edited

Answer (score 0):

```
   val base = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Cricket", "Game", "Outdoor", "India", "yes"), ("Cricket", "Game", "Outdoor", "Australia", "yes"), ("Hockey", "Game", "Outdoor", "India", "yes")))
    base.map(x => (x._1, x)).groupByKey().map(x => { (x._1, x._2.map(x => (x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5))) }).foreach(println)
```

Result:

(Cricket,List((Game,Outdoor,India,yes), (Game,Outdoor,Australia,yes)))
(Hockey,List((Game,Outdoor,India,yes)))